# Why space is being counted as newline in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I wrote the following script. I want to read a file and print as line by line but it considering space as new line. why is that?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat data.txt`
do
echo $i
done
```

Input: Saved in file name **data.txt**

```
B  FM_Server10_grp GPCBIOEMM10          Y          N               ONLINE
```

Output:

```
B
FM_Server10_grp
PCBIOEMM10
Y
N
ONLINE
```

Another question: How can I extract only number value like `10` from `GPCBIOEMM10`?

Comment: Your script isn't doing what you want it to do. backticks substitute the command's output in-place (e.g. the whole file). Also, separate questions should be separate Questions.

Comment: The real problem here is trying to process text in a shell loop.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943.  Also, you don't need a script for what you're doing here, you should just run `cat data.txt` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for i in ...` by default loops over a whitespace-delimited list of tokens, not newline-delimited list of tokens.  Both space and newline are whitespace characters and are therefore considered delimiters.

Consider:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < data.txt
```

read will, by default, read up until a newline and store what it reads in the given variable.